# How to rollback whole Transaction for Splitter incase any submessage fails

Tags: apache-camel, rollback

**Current Use Case**:
With below configuration, we are trying to split Parent message using Custom Iterator processor and assign different endpoints to different submessages inside the test processor, based on its content.

```
from("endpoint")    
    .split().method(iteratorProcessor, "execute")
    .shareUnitOfWork()
    .stopOnException()
    .bean(testProcessor, "process") 
    .receipientList(header("destination"));
```

With the above, success case is working as expected.

**Issue**:
In case after the split, first message posting is successful and second message posting fails, we are observing that second sub message alone is directed to the error handler.

**Requirement**:
If any failure occurs in the entire process, we want to redirect the IN message to error handler(complete rollback) and don't post any other submessages.

Answer (score 0):

The onException clause provides an option to use the original message.

From Camel docs:

```
onException(MyOrderException.class)
.useOriginalMessage()
.handled(true)
.to("jms:queue:order:failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow!

In case of an error, due to the statement `stopOnException()`, the [Splitter](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html) aborts processing.

That means for your **goal to do a complete rollback**

- You are fine for all not yet processed records.
- **Your problem are the already successfully processed records**

For these you have to **run a compensation logic** as part of your rollback. For example if already processed records are written to a database, you could delete them later when a failure in the Splitter occurs.

**Added due to comments**

According to the [Splitter docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html#_sharing_unit_of_work), since you use `shareUnitOfWork()` you should receive **just one error message when the Splitter is done** and at least 1 error occured (instead of one error message per failed submessage). So if you also use `useOriginalMessage()` in your error handler, you should then receive the original IN message.

If this does not work, it **could** collide with `stopOnException()` (never tried this). It would be a try to remove `stopOnException()` and check if it works like this.

You cannot **directly** compensate an already delivered JMS message, but you can build a **compensation that you can trigger afterwards**. For example send the failed messages from the error handler to another queue whose consumer rolls back whatever the first message did.

Comment: Right, while splitting if there is any failure since we are using stopOnException it works fine.
Here our destination is a queue, so if there is any failure within bean or while posting to queue after certain messages are processed. We cannot rollback as the previous once are already committed. So want to check if there is anything from camel to achieve this.
Also, the error handler is receiving the sub message that is split but not actual IN message.

Comment: I extended my answer due to your comment